# Spring Active Directory always gives bad credentials

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to set up Springboot Security to authenticate users using Active Directory.

I've followed this guide:

https://medium.com/@dmarko484/spring-boot-active-directory-authentication-5ea04969f220

And have the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("test.local", "ldap://192.168.0.26:389");
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

    return provider;
}
}
```

I have an Administrator user set up (and can log in to Windows Server 2012 with it fine) and have Active Directory Domain Services installed on the server OK.

However when I sign in (currently using HTTP Basic) I always get "Bad Credentials"

I've tried:
Username: Administrator Password: password
Username: TEST\Administrator Password: password
Username: Administrator@test.local Password: password

however each of these combinations are giving Bad Credentials.

Is there anything else that needs to be set up in AD itself to allow for external log in? Currently I just have a bare bones Windows Server 2012 VM with AD DS installed and configured.

I've also checked the domain using Get-ADDomain on the server and it's correct.

And yes I have checked the username and password spelling....

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Enable DEBUG logging for org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad and see what it says.

Comment: Hi, MC123 did you solve this problem, i am stuck with this since last 15 days. any Help would be appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: KuldeeP ChoudharY - Sorry for the late reply. I haven't worked on this project for over 6 monts now - I remember copying someone's Github example and that got it working - can't remember the repo though, sorry.

Depending on your AD setup (Azure, Windows Server etc) you might end up with a slightly different config. If you're using 2012 R2 or later, or Azure, standard OAuth should work...I think